# Вроде бы деепричастный оборот, но нужно ли отделять запятой?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, деепричастный-оборот

*Не изменил он себе(,) и покидая этот мир.*

Нужна ли запятая в скобках?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Одиночное деепричастие или деепричастный оборот не обособляется:](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=113)

> ...3) если перед деепричастным оборотом стоит усилительная частица
> ***и***: *Можно прожить и не хвастая умом* (М. Г.); *Можете уйти и не дожидаясь ответа; Он оставался скромным и победив сильного
> противника*.

Comment: Век живи, век учи (исключения, которые больше правила). Спасибо!